# Barplot with 2 variables, 2 y-axis

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have the following data

```
test<-data.frame(group=1:10, var.a=rnorm(n=10,mean=500,sd=20), var.b=runif(10))
```

I would like a barplot with 2 y axis (one for var.a, one for var.2). Each group (x axis, 1:10) should have 2 bars next to each other, one for var.a and one for var.b.

I cannot use one y-axis because of the difference morder of magnitude of var.a and var.b

Is this possible with base R?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the `graphics` package in R, one could create new variables as the values in `var.a` and `var.b` converted into proportions of the maximum values in the respective variable:

```
test <- data.frame(group = 1:10, var.a = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 500, sd = 20),
  var.b = runif(10))

funProp <- function(testCol) {
    test[, testCol]/max(test[, testCol])
}

test$var.a.prop <- funProp("var.a")
test$var.b.prop <- funProp("var.b")
```

Then draw the plot using `barplot()` without the axes:

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(test[, c("var.a.prop", "var.b.prop")])), beside = TRUE,
  yaxt = "n", names.arg = test$group)
```

Then add the axes on the left and the right using the original value ranges for the labels (the `labels` argument) and the proportional value ranges to place the labels on the axes (the `at` argument) (this part is not pretty, but it gets the job done):

```
axis(2, at = seq(0, max(test$var.a.prop), length.out = 10),
  labels = round(seq(0, max(test$var.a), length.out = 10)))

axis(4, at = seq(0, max(test$var.b.prop), length.out = 10),
  labels = round(seq(0, max(test$var.b), length.out = 10), 2))
```

(Sorry for the lack of an image)

**EDIT:**

To get the axes a bit `pretty`er,

```
myLeftAxisLabs <- pretty(seq(0, max(test$var.a), length.out = 10))
myRightAxisLabs <- pretty(seq(0, max(test$var.b), length.out = 10))

myLeftAxisAt <- myLeftAxisLabs/max(test$var.a)
myRightAxisAt <- myRightAxisLabs/max(test$var.b)

barplot(t(as.matrix(test[, c("var.a.prop", "var.b.prop")])),
  beside = TRUE, yaxt = "n", names.arg = test$group,
  ylim=c(0, max(c(myLeftAxisAt, myRightAxisAt))))

axis(2, at = myLeftAxisAt, labels = myLeftAxisLabs)

axis(4, at = myRightAxisAt, labels = myRightAxisLabs)
```

Comment: Very clever way. Thank you very much. Is there any way to get the axis to look a bit prettier?

Comment: @ECII, please see the edit above for a suggestion to get prettier axes.